# how to implement "drop" on a generic struct where T itself implements a type

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a generic container struct like this:

```
struct Container<T> {
  data: T,
  key: String
}
```

I want to implement `Drop` for `Container<T>` when `T` implements an additional trait.

For instance:

```
trait Cleanup {
  fn clean(&self);
}
```

I want to implement `Drop` for `Container` in the case that `T: Cleanup`. In my case I have implemented for my concrete type `MyStruct`:

`impl Cleanup for MyStruct { ... }`

I tried to confine the `Drop` impl like so:

```
impl<T> Drop for Container<T> where T: Cleanup {
  fn drop(&mut self) { self.data.cleanup() ; }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
`Drop` impl requires `T: Cleanup` but the struct it is implemented for does not
```

Comment: Well, you can't. You can implement `Drop` only with constraints that appear on the type too.

Comment: stupid question, why does the constraint need to be applied to the container when I am constraining on T?

Comment: `Drop` has to be implemented for all `Container`s. Right now you can construct a `Container` which doesn't implement `Drop` which is illegal.

Comment: `Cleanup` sounds a lot like `Drop`. Is it possible for you to have all `Containers` implement `Drop` in such a way that it only cleans up where there is cleaning up to be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed for `Drop` to only be implemented for *some* instantiations of a type. Since your `Drop` implementation requires that `T: Cleanup`, you need to make sure that `T: Cleanup` for every possible instance of `Container<T>`, i.e. define the struct like this:

```
struct Container<T: Cleanup> {
    data: T,
    key: String
}
```

You can see an explanation like this if you follow the link for the full description for [E0367](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0367), the error code that you got.